# Create an InMemory Wav stream and Play it in a UWP app

Tags: audio, uwp, wav

I have an in memory WAV stream that I am able to play using

```
    mStrm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    new System.Media.SoundPlayer(mStrm).Play();
```

I am trying to see how i can use the same stream and play it in a UWP application. I tried the following code

```
        MediaElement soundPlayer = new MediaElement();
        var soundSource = mStrm.AsRandomAccessStream();
        soundSource.Seek(0);
        soundPlayer.SetSource(soundSource, "audio/wav");
        soundPlayer.Play();
```

But I am receiving the following error

```
    MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED : HRESULT - 0x80000013
```

Adding the code for the audio synthesis that I have taken from web.

```
    public static void PlayBeep(UInt16 frequency, int msDuration, UInt16    volume = 16383)
    {
        var mStrm = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(mStrm);

        const double TAU = 2 * Math.PI;
        int formatChunkSize = 16;
        int headerSize = 8;
        short formatType = 1;
        short tracks = 1;
        int samplesPerSecond = 44100;
        short bitsPerSample = 16;
        short frameSize = (short)(tracks * ((bitsPerSample + 7) / 8));
        int bytesPerSecond = samplesPerSecond * frameSize;
        int waveSize = 4;
        int samples = (int)((decimal)samplesPerSecond * msDuration / 1000);
        int dataChunkSize = samples * frameSize;
        int fileSize = waveSize + headerSize + formatChunkSize + headerSize + dataChunkSize;
        writer.Write(0x46464952);
        writer.Write(fileSize);
        writer.Write(0x45564157);
        writer.Write(0x20746D66);
        writer.Write(formatChunkSize);
        writer.Write(formatType);
        writer.Write(tracks);
        writer.Write(samplesPerSecond);
        writer.Write(bytesPerSecond);
        writer.Write(frameSize);
        writer.Write(bitsPerSample);
        writer.Write(0x61746164); // = encoding.GetBytes("data")
        writer.Write(dataChunkSize);
        {
            double theta = frequency * TAU / (double)samplesPerSecond;
            double amp = volume >> 2;
            for (int step = 0; step < samples; step++)
            {
                short s = (short)(amp * Math.Sin(theta * (double)step));
                writer.Write(s);
            }
        }

        mStrm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        MediaElement soundPlayer = new MediaElement();
        var soundSource = mStrm.AsRandomAccessStream();
        soundSource.Seek(0);
        soundPlayer.SetSource(soundSource, "audio/wav");
        soundPlayer.Play();
        writer.Dispose();
        mStrm.Dispose();
    }
```

And I have am passing the different note frequencies for different octaves in a for loop and the duration is 1000milliseconds.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks,
Teja

Comment: Could you please provide the `mStrm` details? Please give a wav stream for testing on our side.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code for the audio synthesis too.Basically I am trying to go through each note frequency and trying to play that frequency. I used code from online and tested it in Linqpad and its working fine.But when i tried the same code in a UWP app with change to MediaElement its not playing the sound. Any better alternative code for audio synthesis is also appreciated.

Comment: By better I mean any easy available inbuilt API.

Comment: When I remove the `writer.Dispose();` and `mStrm.Dispose();`, then I use the `PlayBeep(8000, 500, 16383) ` to run your code that it works.

Comment: Thanks its working